# List<> Get Next element or get the first

Tags: c#

I want to get the next element in a list and if the list is at it's end I want the first element.
So I just want it to circle in other words.

```
   List<int> agents = taskdal.GetOfficeAgents(Branches.aarhusBranch);
    if (lastAgentIDAarhus != -1)
    {
        int index = agents.IndexOf(lastAgentIDAarhus);
        if (agents.Count > index + 1)
        {
            lastAgentIDAarhus = agents[index + 1];
        }
        else
        {
            lastAgentIDAarhus = agents[0];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lastAgentIDAarhus = agents[0];
    }
```

I am fairly displeased with my own solution shown above, let me know if you have a better one :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
lastAgentIDAarhus = agents[index == -1 ? 0 : index % agents.Count];
```

The use of the MOD operator **%** atuomatically chops the index to the range of possible indexes.

The modulo operator is the compliment to the DIV (/) operator and returns the remainder of a division of two whole numbers. For example if you divide 9 by 6 the result is 1 with a remainder of 3. The MOD operator asks for the 3.

Comment: wow that is an extremely neat solution if that works :)
care to explain it a bit?

Comment: the mod operator does a modulo, which is exactly what you wanted. If you could initialize the index to 0 instead of -1, you could use: lastAgentIDAarhus = agents[index % (agents.Count - 1)]

Comment: I think it should be `index % ( agents.Count )`

Comment: @EricYin: your Count will always be 1 higher than the highest index that you have. This is because (generally) indexes start at 0, while the Count property starts at 1.

Comment: @EricYin is correct. Say you have a list with 10 items and you try to access the item at index 10 (it doesn't exist). 10%10=0 is what you want, not 10%9=1.

Comment: From the code posted in question we can see that TS needs `agents[0]`, not `agents[1]`. Therefore there is no need in `- 1`, I suggested an edit.

Answer (score 15):

Or simply:

```
public static T NextOf<T>(this IList<T> list, T item)
{
    var indexOf = list.IndexOf(item);
    return list[indexOf == list.Count - 1 ? 0 : indexOf + 1];
}
```

Example:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();

names.Add("jonh");
names.Add("mary");

string name = String.Empty;    

name = names.NextOf(null);   //name == jonh

name = names.NextOf("jonh"); //name == mary

name = names.NextOf("mary"); //name == jonh
```

Answer (score 6):

As a slightly different take on this, here's an extension method you could use to make any IEnumerable 'circular'

```
  public static IEnumerable<T> AsCircularEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
  {
    var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
    if(!enumerator.MoveNext())
      yield break;

    while (true)
    {
      yield return enumerator.Current;
      if(!enumerator.MoveNext())
        enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
    }
  }
```

so you could use that like this

```
  var agents = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 123, 234, 345, 546};

  foreach(var i in agents.AsCircularEnumerable())
  {
    Console.WriteLine(i);
  }
```

Which will just keep going... :)

Comment: if there are 3 elements in a list, and if i use an index value of 4 or 5 - to get to an item in the list - will i get the first and second elements of the list?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you are asking about indexing using the solution that I outline above then, as this isn't a list it's an IEnumerable and you can't use an indexer on an IEnumerable, then no, you won't. You could use something like agents.AsCircularEnumerable().Skip(10).First() instead.

Answer (score 4):

I like [Vinicius's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15931918/1015595) of using an extension method. Unfortunately the code he posted will throw an exception. This is based on his, but it will not throw an exception and it is very straightforward and easy to read (IMHO):

```
public static T Next<T>(this IList<T> list, T item)
{
    var nextIndex = list.IndexOf(item) + 1;

    if (nextIndex == list.Count)
    {
        return list[0];
    }

    return list[nextIndex];
}
```

It will return the first item in the list if the item passed in is not in the list, since `list.IndexOf(item)` will return `-1` in that case;

Comment: Koveras, where will raise an exception?

Comment: Remember that list.IndexOf(item) will return -1 if no item is found.

Comment: This is really a nice idea for an extension. I modified it a bit and implemented it :)

Answer (score 2):

Not a great difference, but at least some less code (at least in the editor) ;o)

```
List<int> agents = taskdal.GetOfficeAgents(Branches.aarhusBranch);
if (lastAgentIDAarhus != -1)
{
    int index = agents.IndexOf(lastAgentIDAarhus);
    lastAgentIDAarhus = (agents.Count > index + 1 ? agents[index + 1] : agents[0]); 
}
else
{
    lastAgentIDAarhus = agents[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What do you think if we add some check to avoid common errors ?

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static TType Next<TType>(this IList<TType> list, TType item)
    {
        if (list == null) return default(TType);

        var itemIndex = list.IndexOf(item);
        if (itemIndex < 0) return list.FirstOrDefault();

        var nextIndex = itemIndex + 1;

        return nextIndex >= list.Count 
            ? list.FirstOrDefault() 
            : list[nextIndex];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

string line = lines[lines.FindIndex(x => x.Contains(item)) + 1];