# Collection with Next()

Tags: c#, collections, iterator, .net-4.0

How can I get next element of element to which I have reference in some collection e.g. `List<T>` ?

I am not talking about any loops, etc. I want get just one next (or previous) element

Comment: Can you define what your 'current' element is? Do you mean the element after the one you have a reference to?

Comment: Probably this might help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776725/list-get-next-element-or-get-the-first

Comment: By definition, to get the next (or previous) there must be a concept of `Current`. There isnt in a `List<T>`. Have you looked at `LinkedList<T>`.

Comment: I'm surprised so many people over analyzed the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the most performant, but it should work.  You can even make it an extension method.

```
    public static T GetNext<T>(IList<T> collection, T value )
    {
        int nextIndex = collection.IndexOf(value) + 1;
        if (nextIndex < collection.Count)
        {
            return collection[nextIndex];
        }
        else
        {
            return value; //Or throw an exception
        }
    }
```

And you use it like this:

```
        var list = new List<string> {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
        string current = "B";
        string next = GetNext(list, current);
        Console.WriteLine(next); //Prints C
```

Comment: Only issue is if you have duplicates in the list, it would always hop back to the first copy of the item and never advance past the second copy.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare That's true.

Answer (score 9):

A collection does not have the a concept of "current element". Iterators/Enumerators do. And they have a `MoveNext()` method. And then you can access the current element of that enumerator with `Current`.

You can call `GetEnumerator()` on almost all collections to get an enumerator.

One problem with enumerators is you usually can't copy them nor move them backwards. (Unlike C++ where most collections have more powerful iterators)

Comment: Ok, it's fine, thanx. 
But I just realized, I need also 'previous'. What's now?

Comment: I think this is misunderstanding the OP's intent (either that or I'm misunderstanding).  @Saint has an "element to which I have reference" and he just wants to find the next or previous one.  As long as it's an indexed collection, he just needs to find the index of the element he has, and then increment it (or decrement to find the previous).

Answer (score 1):

To get "next" you need a concept of "current".  C# doesn't use iterators like C++ does, you can either get an enumerator:

```
        var enumerator = x.GetEnumerator();

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);
        }
```

But it would be easier to just use an `int` indexer into the `List<T>`